# Devise: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: email, name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using Rails (3.2.3) and Devise, and allowing administrators to create new users – and edit user accounts.

At this point, administrators can create accounts successfully. However, they can't edit them.

When you try to edit a user's account, a mass-assignment error is raised:

`Can't mass-assign protected attributes: email, name`

Even though, in the User model, these attributes are set to accessible:

`attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me`

What's interesting, is, if I change the above line to `attr_protected`, you CAN edit user information but you CANNOT create users anymore. Very weird.

Here's the relevant code I'm working with... any help is appreciated.

---

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :role_ids, :as => :admin
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

Users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!  
  def update
    authorize! :update, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if params[:user][:password].blank?
      params[:user].delete(:password)
      params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation)
    end

    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user], :as => :admin)
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
    else
      redirect_to users_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
    end
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    if params[:user][:password].blank?
      params[:user].delete(:password)
      params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to users_path, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :role_ids, :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :as => :admin
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

Now administrators can create accounts successfully & they **CAN** edit them as well. Hope it helps

Comment: Worked like a charm (slight typo – name should be :name and :remember_me should be :remember_me,). Thanks for your help!